# Difference between first and second verb conjugations

Tags: глаголы

I'm having trouble understanding when to use the first or second verb conjugation. Could someone throw up some examples?

Comment: Can you give examples of troubles you have?

Comment: Mostly old (who had never bothered to learn proper Russian) or very young people don't make a difference between _читает и читаит*_ on writting, so they do imply the same meanings. What we hear in the speak, is  [_читает=читаит*_](https://translate.yandex.ru/?text=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%3F%20%D0%9E%D0%BD%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE.&lang=ru-en)

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference in ***use***.  They are *just verbs* with their meanings.  Each belongs to either the first or the second conjugation, just like nouns belong to the first, second or third declension (or have gender, or animacy) - **an intrinsic trait of each verb**.

Conjugation governs the *postfixes* (*endings*) of the personal forms of verbs.  All *first conjugation* verbs have "**-ет**" or "**-ёт**" ending in 3rd person singular present tense.  All *second conjugation* verbs have "**-ит**" ending in 3rd person singular present tense.

There are exceptions, but your favourite book should tell you about those.

Examples can be found on [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_grammar#Verbs).